# Configuring web.xml in resteasy

Tags: java, resteasy

I am using a RESTeasy and want to host the web application on the url
http://localhost:8080/rest/JAXRS-RESTEasy/, now it is hosted on
http://localhost:8080/JAXRS-RESTEasy/rest/

How I have to change the current web.xml?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>JAXRS-RESTEasy</display-name>
    
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- this should be the same URL pattern as the servlet-mapping property -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
        <param-value>/rest</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.javacodegeeks.enterprise.rest.resteasy.MyRESTApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>      
</web-app>
```

The java code

```
package com.javacodegeeks.enterprise.rest.resteasy;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
 

    public class MyRESTApplication  extends Application {
        
        private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();
         
        public MyRESTApplication() {
            singletons.add(new RESTEasyHelloWorldService());
        }
     
        @Override
        public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
            return singletons;
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: What servlet container or application server are you running in?

Comment: I am using JBOSS

Comment: Which version? Newer versions it should be pretty easy.

Comment: It is Red Hat JBoss 7.3

Comment: The thing is how can I ignore the project url?

Comment: What do you mean by the "project url"? The "JAXRS-RESTEasy" part?